# SQL find duplicate Addresses with Abbreviations or Shorten Address

Tags: php, mysql

I don't even know if this possible or can even be done through a MySQL query. I have searched the site and find many solutions on finding dups based on a full address. But what if the address is not identical. Can a dup check still be performed; or do I have to do this through PHP.

Here are a few scenarios.

25 Somerset St and 25 Somerset Street
253 Darling BV and 253 Darling Boulevard
2536 Bluewater HWY, 2536 Bluewater HW and 2536 Bluewater Hi-Way

All samples are the same address, just inputed differently. Can SQL search for duplicates with an array of common abbreviated combinations or can a search be performed by search for just "25 Somerset" or "253 Darling"?

This is beyond my SQL knowledge and if any of these are possible, can I be pointed to a solution already being used?

I can implement it into a few solutions I found on here to see if I can pull off the complete query.

Comment: You can do so in SQL by writing an SQL function that'll take both queries, strip off certain words (for example, 'street', 'st', 'boulevard', 'bv', etc.) only if they are the last words in the string, do string comparison of the stripped strings, return 1 if they are equal and 0 if they are not, and then call this function from your query. This logic will probably be easier to implement in PHP than SQL though.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the first part of a string in SQL by using a wildcard in the WHERE clause.

WHERE address_column like '25 Somerset%'

But you should know that many cities have distinct street names like these.

- Potter St
- Potter Way
- Potter Ave
- NW Potter Ave
- Potter Blvd

Also, think about adding an index to address_column.

To reliably reject or correct a misspelling like "25 Summerset", you probably need to call a third-party API. In the US, the USPS has one.

Comment: This wouldn't work, the addresses are Canadian and the combinations are way to vast. I was hoping for one query to look for all matches at once.